# Start/stop services from command prompt under non Administrator user, but belonging to administrators group

Tags: windows-7, command-line, administrator, uac

I have a WIN7 computer with user which is in Administrator group. Let's call it MyUser.
UAC turned ON.
I have several services launched under local system.
When I'm trying to start or stop these services via MyUser account  from command prompt (without  "Run as Administrator" option checked), I'm obviously have "Access denied" error.

But in the same time I have another computer with Windows-server 2008, where the command prompt under the same user (i.e. it's from Administrator group, but nothing more) launches by default as Administrator.
And I can't understand HOW, because checkbox "Run as Administrator" in Shortcut->Advanced is turned off, so it's happened somehow else.

I want to do the same for Win7 computer. What I should do?

And small addition: Is it possible to do without notify user that Command prompt tries to start under administrator when UAC turned on?

Comment: You can bypass UAC prompts by creating a task in the task scheduler that will open your command line or runs your command and tick the box "Run with highest privileges".

To execute, you execute the task itself from the command line.

Comment: One reason it works on the Windows Server 2008 is because thats based on Windows Vista.  The same thing wouldn't work on Windows Server 2008 R2.